# Why does Pidgin start twice?

Tags: xubuntu, chromium, pidgin, session

I am using Xubuntu. When I boot it up, pidgin comes in twice and chromium starts. I want only pidgin to start once, and no chromium. Also, if I completely kill all pidgin and reboot, it only comes up once. Pidgin is on the autostart menu, but I do not have it checked. Chromium is not. I have also disabled saving the session on logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under pidgin
Tool->Preferences->Interface->Set "show system tray icon" to "always"

Comment: I am having the same issue, but "Show system tray icon" is already set to "always". Is there any other reason it might be doing this?